# React Native NativeModules pass multiple functions in one object

Tags: javascript, objective-c, react-native

I'm working with React Native, trying to create a native module which can accept a NSDictionary of functions. For example, suppose I want to call a function that has multiple potential callbacks. Suppose I could have 0 callbacks, 15, or any number inbetween. I use a dictionary so I only include the callback functions I want to use:

```
MyModule.showInterstitial({
    onLoad:()=>{console.log("Loaded")},
    failedToLoad:()=>{console.log("Failed to load")},
    onDismiss:()=>{console.log("Did dismiss")},
})
```

This makes  a lot more sense coming from someone using an API to have the code look like this, rather than something like the following with 15 different callbacks and only 3 being used:

```
MyModule.showInterstitial(null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    ()=>{console.log("Loaded")},
    null,
    null,
    ()=>{console.log("Failed to load")},
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    ()=>{console.log("Did dismiss")},
    null
})
```

When I look at my Objective C code, I can try to create a method like this:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(showInterstitial: (NSDictionary *)callbacks) {
    // implementation
}
```

But the problem with this ObjC method is that the NSDictionary creates a NSDictionary of NSDictionaries (in other words RCTConvert has no method to convert a javascript function into a RCTResponseSenderBlock). I've tried casting it, and it doesn't work. And my app crashes if I just try to call it.

So I'm wondering if anyone has dealt with this before or knows how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

For a use case like this I think you should consider using an event API in JavaScript and have your bridge module extend `RCTEventEmitter`. The bridge infrastructure is designed more for data inputs and outputs, not functions. You could have events for `load` and `dismiss` which the bridge module fires and your JS can subscribe as needed. The `showInterstitial` method could use a return callback to return a synchronous error/success.

Change your bridge module to extend `RCTEventEmitter` and then use `[self sendEventWithName:body:]` when you need to fire the load and dismiss events.

Hope this helps...